# Rainbow Parenthesis for Lisp in Vim

Tags: filetype-lisp

I just found out about this option in vim !!!

```
let g:lisp_rainbow = 1
```

It's pretty exciting to learn something so useful. I can't figure out how to customize it though. Specially, I want to expel the prominent red colored parenthesis out of the available options.

I know I can do it with some plugins. But there are so many, and few (two actually) of which I tried did not work as expected. Bear in mind, I don't particularly want this rainbow parenthesis functionality for any other filetypes except `lisp`. So, I would be happy with stock options, no plugin.

So, how do I customize this option in [neo]vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume when you say "customize" you don't mean anything besides changing the parentheses colors. Look in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/lisp.vim` and search for "lisp_rainbow" and you'll find this

```
   if &bg == "dark"
    hi def hlLevel0 ctermfg=red         guifg=red1
    hi def hlLevel1 ctermfg=yellow      guifg=orange1
    hi def hlLevel2 ctermfg=green       guifg=yellow1
    hi def hlLevel3 ctermfg=cyan        guifg=greenyellow
    hi def hlLevel4 ctermfg=magenta     guifg=green1
    hi def hlLevel5 ctermfg=red         guifg=springgreen1
    hi def hlLevel6 ctermfg=yellow      guifg=cyan1
    hi def hlLevel7 ctermfg=green       guifg=slateblue1
    hi def hlLevel8 ctermfg=cyan        guifg=magenta1
    hi def hlLevel9 ctermfg=magenta     guifg=purple1
   else
    hi def hlLevel0 ctermfg=red         guifg=red3
    hi def hlLevel1 ctermfg=darkyellow  guifg=orangered3
    hi def hlLevel2 ctermfg=darkgreen   guifg=orange2
    hi def hlLevel3 ctermfg=blue        guifg=yellow3
    hi def hlLevel4 ctermfg=darkmagenta guifg=olivedrab4
    hi def hlLevel5 ctermfg=red         guifg=green4
    hi def hlLevel6 ctermfg=darkyellow  guifg=paleturquoise3
    hi def hlLevel7 ctermfg=darkgreen   guifg=deepskyblue4
    hi def hlLevel8 ctermfg=blue        guifg=darkslateblue
    hi def hlLevel9 ctermfg=darkmagenta guifg=darkviolet
   endif
```

So just override whatever colors you want. This command will change the first level of red to blue:

```
:hi hlLevel0 ctermfg=blue guifg=blue
```

Don't know if you can just put this line in your vimrc...it may depend on what order things are loaded, when/where you set g:lisp_rainbow, etc. Worse comes to worst, you could add an `autocommand` for filetype lisp in vimrc and add your overrides to that.

Comment: Awesome, I should've looked myself, don't know why didn't think of that. But thankyou. And for you question, if you can put it in your vimrc, I just put it after loading my colorscheme.

Comment: You're welcome. So `vim foo.lisp` is a straightforward case but what if you are opening different file types in addition to `.lisp`, jumping between them, changing color scheme on the fly, etc. Does it seem pretty stable with simple override in vimrc?

Comment: When opening *.java, *.cpp along with *.elisp files, the customization holds, but I don't know about changing colorschemes on the fly. I don't think that's very important, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I have to suggest [this plugin](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow) for you, it is Highly configurable, to just enable rainbow parentheses for lisp, you can configure it like following:

```
let g:rainbow_conf = {
\   'separately': {
\       '*': 0,
\       'lisp': {
\           'guifgs': ['royalblue3', 'darkorange3', 'seagreen3', 'darkorchid3'],
\       }
\   }
\}
```